JSON.parse not parsing local storage data | Jquery/Javascript
I need to save user input, push to an array, then stringify to local storage. Those parts are seemingly working perfectly fine

except when I try to parse the data back out.
![inputs being displayed on webpage as object Object
I've tried looking at a couple forums, but I haven't found something that works on this.
My code is saving user inputs to local storage.
// Todo: create a function to handle adding a new task
function handleAddTask(event) {

    //taskTitle
    //datepicker
    //taskDescr
    
        //  const title = taskTitle.value;
        // const date = datepicker.value;
        // const desc = taskDescr.value;
    
        let Cake = {
            title: taskTitle.value,
            date: datepicker.value,
            desc: taskDescr.value,
        }
    
            fruitCake.push({Cake});
    
        localStorage.setItem('fruitCake', JSON.stringify(fruitCake));
        // localStorage.setItem('title', title);
        // localStorage.setItem('date', date);
        // localStorage.setItem('desc', desc)
}

They're all being called, it's  pushing to
let fruitCake = [];
this array as near as I can tell.
function fork(){
    handleAddTask();
    renderTaskList();
}

gregory();

$("#test").on('click', createTaskCard);
$("#pikap").click(fork);

I thought the issue was here:
function gregory() {

    const perry = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('fruitCake'));

    if (perry !== null) {
        fruitCake = perry;
    }

    renderTaskList();
}

But someone said inside of the fruitCake.push({Cake}); it wasn't pushing because cake was already an object so it was an object inside an object.
I asked if I needed to change one of the cakes then and never got an answer, so now I'm kind of more confused than when I started.
I tried changing the names of one of the cakes, but it didn't work.
Website's issue, throwing up objects instead of parsing the data:

This is the data responsible for rendering it. I thought I had to parse it in here originally, but whatever I tried didn't work.
function renderTaskList() {
    // const strawberry = window.localStorage.getItem("fruitCake");
    // const banana = JSON.parse(user_id)["fruitCake"]
    
    // const value = localStorage.getItem("fruitCake");
    // return JSON.parse(value);
       
        // todoList.innerHTML = '';
        // todoCountSpan.textContent = fruitCake.length;

        //render a new box
    for (let i = 0; i < fruitCake.length; i++){
        const froot = fruitCake[i];

        const li = document.createElement('li');
        li.textContent = froot; 
        li.setAttribute('data-index', i);

        const button = document.createElement('button');
        button.textContent = 'X';

        li.appendChild(button);
        todoList.appendChild(li); 
        console.log("bg3 good");
    }
} 


Show us the code that's responsible for rendering the list. Looks like you're trying to write the whole object instead of a string property to the DOM. This implicitly invokes the toString() method of the object which returns "[object Object]".

You are pushing fruitCake.push({Cake}); which is a shorthand for fruitCake.push({Cake: Cake}); So in your template you probably have to set data.Cake instead of data (or just don't push it in an object

Cake is already an object, you don't need to wrap it inside {}.

@Lennholm i added the code for rendering to the end of the main post

@Yunios So you're trying to set the entire wrapped object as textContent of your LI element. What you need to do is use one of the string properties instead. If it's for instance the title you want to display, you do li.textContent = froot.Cake.title;

fruitCake.push({Cake}) results in [ 0: { Cake: { title: '', date: '', desc: '' } } ].
fruitCake[0] returns { Cake: { title: '', date: '', desc: '' } }.
If you instead do fruitCake.push(Cake) it results in [ 0: { title: '', date: '', desc: '' } ].
fruitCake[0] then returns { title: '', date: '', desc: '' }.
In your renderTaskList function you're doing li.textContent = froot which is like doing li.textContent = { title: '', date: '', desc: '' }. As you can see, the text content is being set to an object.
You need to instead set the text content to a property of the object: li.textContent = froot.title;.
